# Sly parser, how are recursively defined types implemented?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, sly

I am new to compiler techniques and started to translate the code below to Matlab.

https://github.com/jol-jol/pymatlabparser/blob/master/pymatlabparser/matlab_parser.py

The tokenizer is done, I have started a simple shift/reduce parser.
But no rule seems to yield 'expr' without requiring it in its pattern.

Where does this magic happen, by built-in Python functions and types?
An idea how to implement it in Matlab?

Comment: The base case is `@_('NAME', 'NUMBER', 'STRING')`, which is the last pattern for `expr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k).

In

```
@_('NAME', 'NUMBER', 'STRING')                  # e.g. x, 56, 3e-2, "example"
def expr(self, p):
    return (p[0],)      # creates a tuple for the token to avoid strings getting concatenated later on
```

I was missing the def expr part. So expr is not created as a token type, but as a function.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your answer if you feel it answered your question. :)